# php email form attachments wrong

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments

So I have a php file that sends info from my form along with an attachment to specified email addresses.  Everything works, but when the files arrive in email form, the attachments don't work and show up with the wrong file type. I am still learning php.  Any guidance would be helpful.

Here is the php code.`

```
<?php 
//Keep people happy, send email by state
$firstbdestates = array("CT", "DE", "ME", "MA", "MD", "NH", "NJ", "NY", "PA", "RI", "WV", "VT", "VA"); 
$secondbdestates = array("AL", "GA", "FL", "MS", "NC", "PR", "SC", "TN");
$thirdbdestates = array("IN", "IL", "IA", "KY", "MI", "MN", "ND", "NE", "OH", "SD", "WI");
$fourthbdestates = array("AZ", "AR", "CO", "KS", "LA", "MO", "NM", "OK", "TX");
$fifthbdestates = array("AK", "CA", "HI", "ID", "MT", "NV", "OR", "UT", "WA", "WY");
$test = array("test"); //test email so I don't piss off BDE CO's
// died and error are interchangeable names, anything listed as "died" will display on  generated page.
function died($error) {
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please use your back button to go  back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}
// Backasswords validation.  All data listed here in '' will trigger  error if not filled out in its entirety.
if(!isset($_POST['mname']) || //A-Za-z- only
!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['streetline1']) ||
!isset($_POST['towncity']) || //A-Za-z- only
!isset($_POST['state']) ||
!isset($_POST['zip']) ||
!isset($_POST['dob']) ||
!isset($_POST['servicebranch']) ||
!isset($_POST['discharge']) ||
!isset($_POST['ratemos']) ||
!isset($_POST['yearsservice']) ||
!isset($_POST['econtactname']) || //A-Za-z- only
!isset($_POST['econtactnumber'])  ||
!isset($_POST['ndaagree']) ||
!isset($_POST['username']) ||
!isset($_POST['password']) ||
!isset($_POST['tosagree']) ||
!isset($_POST['wolagree'])) {
died('<span style="color:#ff0000">One or more fields were not filled out.</span>');       
}
//email validation
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 }
// Simple sanitization for unwanted characters A-Za-z- only
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$mname)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
   }
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$towncity)) {
    $error_message .= 'The town or city you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
   }
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$econtactname)) {
    $error_message .= 'The emergency contact name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
   }

// Callout all form data...WHAT A BITCH!
$mname = $_POST['mname']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // required
$streetline1 = $_POST['streetline1']; // required
$streetline2 = $_POST['streetline2']; // required
$towncity = $_POST['towncity']; // required
$state = $_POST['state']; // required
$zip = $_POST['zip']; // required
$dob = $_POST['dob']; // required
$servicebranch = $_POST['servicebranch']; // required
$discharge = $_POST['discharge']; // required
$ratemos = $_POST['ratemos']; // required
$yearsservice = $_POST['yearsservice']; // required
$econtactname = $_POST['econtactname']; // required
$econtactnumber = $_POST['econtactnumber']; // required
$ndaagree = $_POST['ndaagree']; // required
$username = $_POST['username']; // required
$password = $_POST['password']; // required
$tosagree = $_POST['tosagree']; // required
$wolagree = $_POST['wolagree']; // required
//
//
//callout for error message
$error_message = "";
//Turn on error reporting so I can see what I screw up
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// FIle Upload to server---Then pull from server
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
    $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt"); // Allowed file types
    $files = array();
    foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
        $file_name = $file['name']; 
        $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $file['type'];
        $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
        $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
            die("Either you did not select a file or it is an incorrect file type.  Please try again.");
        }
        array_push($files,$file);
    }
    //If NO ERRORS, proceed
    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on and so on.  Format pretty so people smile
    $to = myFunction();
    $from = "webmaster@warriorpointe.org"; 
    $subject ="$mname has requested to Join";
    $message = "<span style='color:#ff0000';>*** This email contains sensitive member information ***</span><br />
                Greetings BDE CO, <br />
                Today, $mname has requested to join Warrior Pointe and they are within your brigade limits. You are receiving this message because they are assigned. Please ensure that you set up the members forum account.  If you are unable to, please notify Patrick or Robert and they can build it for you.<br />
                <span style='color:#ff0000'>*** This email contains sensitive member information ***</span><br /><br /><br />
                ";
    // Geek Translator - all this crap in English so I don't get yelled at
    $message .="Members Name: ".clean_string($mname)."\n <br /> Contact Number: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n <br /> Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n <br /> Street Address: ".clean_string($streetline1)."\n <br /> Street Address 2: ".clean_string($streetline2)."\n <br /> Town or City: ".clean_string($towncity)."\n <br /> State: ".clean_string($state)."\n <br /> Zip Code: ".clean_string($zip)."\n <br /> Date of Birth: ".clean_string($dob)."\n <br /> Branch of Service: ".clean_string($servicebranch)."\n <br /> Discharge Status: ".clean_string($discharge)."\n <br /> Rate or MOS: ".clean_string($ratemos)."\n <br /> Years of Service: ".clean_string($yearsservice)."\n <br /> Emergency Contact Name: ".clean_string($econtactname)."\n <br /> Emergency Contact Number: ".clean_string($econtactnumber)."\n <br /> NDA Agreement: ".clean_string($ndaagree)."\n <br /> Waiver of Liability: ".clean_string($wolagree)."\n <br /> Forum TOS Agree: ".clean_string($tosagree)."\n <br /> Forum User Name: ".clean_string($username)."\n <br /> Forum Password: ".clean_string($password)."\n <br />"; 
    $message .="<span style='color:#ff0000'>*** END OF MESSAGE ***</span>";
    // Tell them who the message is from
    $headers = "From: $from";
    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  
    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";  
    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $name = $files[$x]['name'];
        $message .= "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }
    // send the form Jeeves 
    $ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    if ($ok) { 
         echo "<img src='images/png/apple-touch-icon-128.png'><br />Thank you for registering with Warrior Pointe.  You registration form has already been forwarded to the correct brigade staff for processing.  Typical processing time is no more than 72 hours.  If you have not heard form brigade staff within 72 hours, please email webmaster@warriorpointe.org.<br/><br/>";
                } else {
                    echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';
                }
    }
// This is how the dang sender knows who to mail too.
function myFunction() {
    if (in_array($_POST['state'], $GLOBALS["firstbdestates"])) {
        return "1stbdecommander@warriorpointe.org, hr@warriorpointe.org, webmaster@warriorpointe.org, archive@warriorpointe.org";
    } 
    else if (in_array($_POST['state'], $GLOBALS["secondbdestates"])) {
        return "2ndbdecommander@warriorpointe.org, hr@warriorpointe.org, webmaster@warriorpointe.org, archive@warriorpointe.org";
    } 
    else if (in_array($_POST['state'], $GLOBALS["thirdbdestates"])) {
        return "3rdbdecommander@warriorpointe.org, hr@warriorpointe.org, webmaster@warriorpointe.org, archive@warriorpointe.org"; 
    } 
    else if (in_array($_POST['state'], $GLOBALS["fourthbdestates"])) {
     return "4thbdecommander@warriorpointe.org, hr@warriorpointe.org, webmaster@warriorpointe.org, archive@warriorpointe.org";
    } 
    else if (in_array($_POST['state'], $GLOBALS["fifthbdestates"])) {
        return "5thbdecommander@warriorpointe.org, hr@warriorpointe.org, webmaster@warriorpointe.org, archive@warriorpointe.org "; 
    }
    else if (in_array($_POST['state'], $GLOBALS["test"])) {
        return "webmaster@warriorpointe.org";
    } 
    else {
        return "president@warriorpointe.org, webmaster@warriorpointe.org, 

archive@warriorpointe.org";
        }

}
function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);}
?>`
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and post your HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php mailer class like this to send attachment

Here is the class https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php

And here is the code of how to send the attachment

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
        $mail->SetFrom('abc@abc.com', 'abc@abc.com');
        $address = 'xyz@xyz.com';
        $mail->Subject = 'test';
        $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional

        $mail->MsgHTML('this is test message');
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->AddAttachment("images/logo1.png"); // attachment
        $mail->AddAttachment("images/engr mudasir.jpg"); // attachment

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo $output = $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo $output = 'thank you';
        }
```